# How to write GET REST API with Node.js, Express,MS SQL to insert data into db with multiple parameters?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest, express, get

I'm working on a REST API Get request to insert new data with multiple parameters into a SQL database, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client
const { request } = require('http');

// Connection string parameters.
var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'serveraddress',
    database: 'databasename'
}

// Start server and listen on http://localhost:8081/
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

app.get("/item/insert/:name/:category/:color/:description/:numberOfUsage/:size/:status", function(req , res){
    console.log(req.params)
        sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        var stringRequest = "INSERT INTO dbo.Item (name, category, color, description, numberOfUsage, size, status) VALUES ("+ req.query.name +","+ req.query.category+","+ req.query.color+","+ req.query.description+","+req.query.numberOfUsage+","+req.query.size+","+req.query.status+" )";
        request.query(stringRequest, function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
            });
        });
    })
```

If i try to insert a new item via browser like "http://localhost:8081/item/insert/MyNewShirt/Shirt/Red/Thatsmynewshirt/1/L/1" returns always status 200 - OK, but the IDE console prints the "RequestError: Invalid column name 'undefined'."
What its mean? How solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. First the new code:

```
app.get("/item/insert/:name/:category/:color/:description/:numberOfUsage/:size/:status", function(req , res){
        sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        var stringRequest = "INSERT INTO dbo.Item (name, category, color, description, numberOfUsage, size, status) VALUES ('"+ req.params.name +"','"+ req.params.category+"','"+ req.params.color+"','"+ req.params.description+"','"+req.params.numberOfUsage+"','"+req.params.size+"','"+req.params.status+"')";
        console.log(stringRequest)
        request.query(stringRequest, function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
            });
        });
    })
```

The only two things I had to change were:

1. Parameters: 'req.query' to 'req.params'
2. SQL Statement: Instead of using " just using ' to close the VALUES

Answer (score 0):

Because you're directly accessing params value to it's name like
In Express you need to get query string variables via **req.query** like this for all params. like in this query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Item (name, category, color, description, numberOfUsage, size, status) VALUES ("+ req.query.name +","+ req.query.category+","+ req.query.color+","+ req.query.description+","+req.query.numberOfUsage+","+req.query.size+","+req.query.status+" )"
```

change all values like shows below

```
var name = req.query.name;
```

Otherwise, in NodeJS, you can access [req.url](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) and the builtin `url` module to [url.parse]
(https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) it manually:

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```